# How to get a GitHub Action step to run only on branches with a particular name prefix?

Tags: github-actions

I am writing a GitHub Action. I want some of my steps to run only on certain branches.

The whole action is set to run only on **master** and on branches beginning with **features/lr**.

```
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - master
      - features/lr*
```

I have a "deploy" step that I want to run on **master** and on branches beginning with **features/lrd**. (So for example if my branch is named **features/lr-foo**, then the deployment step should be skipped.)

I know I can do `if` conditionals like this:

```
- name: Deploy application
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
```

Can I also check whether `github.ref` matches a certain prefix or pattern? What is the syntax for that?

Something like this pseudocode:

```
- name: Deploy application
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' || github.ref.matches('refs/heads/lrd*')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the answer from frennky, I ended up doing the following in my step, which is ugly but works:

```
- name: Deploy application
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' || startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/features/lrd')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `branches`, `branches-ignore`, `tags`, and `tags-ignore` keywords accept glob patterns. You can check details in docs - [filter pattern](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet).

As for using expressions, docs don't mention `matches` function, but maybe you could use something like `contains`, `startsWith` or `endsWith`. See [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#functions) for details.